# How select random items by given categories in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I have a table with items with category id-s and I want to create a function that gets category ids array and returns an array of random items with corresponding categories.
Here is what I've tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_random_items(IN args uuid[])
    RETURNS SETOF items
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100    ROWS 1000 
    
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    cat_id uuid;
    output items[];
BEGIN
 FOREACH cat_id IN ARRAY args LOOP
    EXECUTE (
        SELECT *
        FROM items
        WHERE category_id = cat_id
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 1
    ) INTO output;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM output;
END $BODY$;
```

And when running -
`SELECT * FROM get_random_items('{d59f2779-4868-439c-96eb-b5a735135379}')`.
I get this error -
`ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`.
Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one random item per category, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.category_id) i.*
FROM items
ORDER BY i.category_id, random();
```

To put this in an array, use aggregation:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.category_id) i.*
      FROM items i
      ORDER BY i.category_id, random()
     ) i;
```

I'm not sure if you really need to put this in a function, but you can if you like.